# How to handle a chain of OneToMany relationships in QueryDSL?

Tags: spring, repository, querydsl

Thus far I have referred to [this repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/tree/master/jdbc) as a reference for how to structure my repositories in my Spring project which leverages QueryDSL.

The only "shortcoming" of this example for me is that it does not outline how I might write a Repository which uses a chain of more than one OneToMany relationships. Using this repository as an example/reference, they have a "Customer" repository and for each Customer there are many "Address". I'm unsure how I would use give or take the same patterns they are using, but for a Class which had a OneToMany relationship with Customers. Meaning, how would I handle a Repository for "CustomerGroup" which has a OneToMany relationship with "Customers" which in turn has a one to many relationship with "Addresses".

Some patterns have occurred to me, but not seem elegant/optimal so I'm looking for anyone with experience or insight as to what might be a nice way of solving this problem.

I very much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean in order to write WHERE statements based on the relations?

For example if you want to retrieve all customer groups that contain a customer from a specific country, you can simply call

```
QCustomerGroup.customerGroup.customer.any().addresses.any().country.eq("Germany")
```

To make this working to need to add

```
@OneToMany
private Address addresses;
```

to the `Customer` entity.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I do have all the correct annotations. Using two any() in the path like that with an eq on the end does produce a query, but not one that actually returns anything different than if the where clause had nothing in it at all